# getview() method is not getting called at times in listview using custom Adapter.

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, getview

I used a custom Adapter to display images using image url. Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes getview() is not being called. I can't find any error from my code.

```
public class GridViewAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewVariables> {

private final Activity context;
private final List<ListViewVariables> list;
DisplayImageOptions doption=null;
private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener =null;
ImageLoader imageLoader= null;

public GridViewAdapter(Activity context, List<ListViewVariables> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public ListViewVariables getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    protected ImageView image;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
  imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
    imageLoader.displayImage(list.get(position).getImageUrl(), holder.image,doption,animateFirstListener);
    return view;
```

}

for displaying the image i am using image loader and calling function is given below:

```
list = EventManagementResuableClass.getResponseFromServer(
                    EventManagenmentConstant.responseStatus_object,
                    EventActivity.this, jsonObj);
            adapter = new GridViewAdapter(EventActivity.this, list);
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Normally I get the list. But certain times getview() doesn't seem to get executed. What will be  the exact problem?

Comment: what do you mean with "getview() is not calling"? Have you tried putting around some Log.d() or debugging? Or you just assumed getView() is not getting called because the images are not showing?

Comment: i came to know that getview() is not called after i debug my code.

Comment: I thing you have not properly debugged it.Trying removing the adapter clear method and try

Comment: when i avoid adapter.clear(), the list items will get repeated in the same page while i am loading  list view.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the following lines??

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Try without those lines...

Comment: When i avoid these lines, the list items will get repeated in the same page with multiple click.

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand.. Can you explain in detail... And the one case when the getView won't be called is when getCount returns 0. Did you check that?!!!

Comment: Yes,sometimes getCount() returns 0 values, not always. how to make it return stable values.

Comment: `list = EventManagementResuableClass.getResponseFromServer(`
`EventManagenmentConstant.responseStatus_object,`
`EventActivity.this, jsonObj);`                                Check the 'size' of 'list' after this line... the size is dynamic and giving zero , then there is nothing wrong with listview or your adapter... Instead the problem is with the list you are getting from server

Comment: Yeah! when i remove adapter.clear it will work fine. but item get repeat in the listview

Comment: get repeat?!! Do you mean there are extra rows or some rows are not getting updated

Comment: No. if we avoid using adapter.clear() count of list_items in the listview repeats each  time when page load

Comment: Remove final keyword from these lines.  `private final Activity context;  private final List<ListViewVariables> list;  final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();`                                    and move these lines to constructor  `imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();`
    `imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));`